# getting Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable issue in async method python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have following code which is giving issue.

```
async def main(event, context):
   print("Begin Main")
   task = asyncio.create_task(someAsyncMethod())

async def someAsyncMethod():
    print("inside async method")
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main('',''))
```

tried printing logs in the main method but it is not getting inside the main method.

please guide me as I am new to this asyncio.

I am getting Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable issue